# Evidence to not use SELECT *

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

My chief architect at work is a genius and I've learned so much from him, but he doesn't agree with NOT using `SELECT *` in our application queries.

His reason is that it doesn't matter much when you're pulling 10 rows, we end pulling 100+ columns just to show 4 to the user.

He's open to discussion which is great and that's why I'm looking online for resources that display hard evidence on SQL query times or something along those lines to present to him.

And, I'm also looking for a way to track those statistics in my app without using up too much CPU (we use .NET 4.0 framework). Thanks for your help

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: Why don't you benchmark the two and compare the results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is SELECT \* considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: do you mean, if we need 10 column out of 100, use select *?

Comment: The answer is .... it depends.

Comment: I think the main argument against the use of the `*` wildcard column in SQL is not really one of performance but that its use makes it harder to figure out what went wrong after the table layouts have subtly changed.

Comment: In SQL server, when you create indexes, you can have the index include extra columns cached along side the indexed columns - the indexed columns make it easy to satisfy `where` clauses and the 'included' columns make it easy to satisfy `from` clauses. If you need to select columns that aren't in the index, it has to go to the primary key index (if one exists) or scan through the entire table if no suitable index exists to find the other columns. `SELECT *` kills index hitrates and circumvents non-clustered indexes.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting together a table with several columns varbinary(max) containing a few large files...and execute the query remotely..